# Resultset in jdbc not returing values

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to jdbc. I had a scenario like, I need to check whether the user exists or not in users tale in database using jdbc. Code written is :

Java class :

```
         public static boolean isUserExists(String username , String password)
         {
        int count=60;
        Connection con = JdbcConnUtil.getJDBCConnection();
        PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("Select count(*) from users where username=? and password=?");
        psmt.setString(1, username);
        psmt.setString(2, password);
        System.out.println(username +"------------"+password);
        ResultSet rs= psmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            double numberOfRows = rs.getDouble(1);
         }
        }
```

In oracle database,i have inserted data as tempuser and temppassowrd in users table and while login in jsp page, I am using the same data. numberofRows variable should return 1 but It is also returning 0. Please help me where I am lagging.

Comment: Did you forget to call **commit** after inserting the data in database?

Comment: Make sure that passed values are exactly same as you inserted in database. **case sensitive and no spaces**

Comment: Blasted my problem in seconds ... thank you, yes ..I didn't commited.. Now it is working fine ...

Comment: Either delete the post or edit it in your post as well.